# Why should I not include "une" in the sentence below?

Tags: articles

Can someone explain the grammatical reason why it is not correct to include *un* after the verb *traiter*?

> « *Comment osez-vous me traiter **de vieille fille** ?* »
>
> « *Comment osez-vous me traiter **d'une vieille fille** ?* » This is wrong, I know. But why?

Comment: I think it's just yet another rule you have to learn, like how with professions or nationalities you don't generally use "un/une" either.  Some people have suggested some explanations, like you don't use an article in front of an adjective but I am not sure how accurate these are.  But just to be clear about the previous remark, here the whole description would work as an adjective, so we're not talking about calling a girl, old, but calling her an "old maid".  For instance you could replace that adjective with racist: "traiter de raciste".  Not sure if this is helpful but let me know...

Comment: It's not just "traiter", it's "traiter de" that calls for an *adj* without "un". There is also "traiter comme", that calls for "un + *noun*" (*Comment osez-vous me traiter comme une vielle personne ?*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can try to explain this, but forgive me if I make a detour through the general case [if anyone sees something to add or to amend, please come forth].

**Meanings of a singular noun**

First of all, we should note that a singular substantive (noun) may have four meanings (in French, but also in other langages):

> 1. A specific object (*le chapeau*)
> 2. An object, but unspecific (*un chapeau*)
> 3. A quantity of a certain material, or quality ["uncountable“]
> 4. A quantity of standardized (measurable) material or a standard category of enumerable objects

While the first 2 are clear for most people, the last ones tend to create difficulties.

**The magic word "de" (from)**

> In French, the word "**de**" is used for these two cases.

Without going into too much grammatical mechanics, we can say that it comes from the Latin preposition *de*, which meant originally "**from**" in the sense of location (*de urbe* = from the city -- and btw the verb "derive" <= *de-ripare* <= *de* + *ripare* <= from + to flow, hence "to flow from"). So the word *de* means the origin, where something is coming from.

But "de" can be also be used, very importantly, for **classes** of objects or **quantities** of material (conceptually, you are drawing something **from** a shelf, or a recipient, etc.).

Note that it can be used for other things, especially to replace the Latin genitive ("Joe's hat" => *le chapeau **de** Joe*, litterally "the hat *from* Joe") or to express a connection (*la ville **de** Paris*)

**Rule for a quantity (3)**

> a) Use **de** + defined article
>
> b) *de* + *le* is always contracted into **du**
>
> c) In the negative, the article is dropped
>
> *du pain*, *de la limonade*, *du courage*, *ne... pas **de** pain*

[Why rule c) would be interesting; my best guess is that since the original Latin construction had no articles anyway, inserting an article into the already awkward construction of the negative was not very practical; hence French took the least effort path. But perhaps there is another way to explain this.]

**Standardized quantity/category (4)**

> **de** + noun (no article)

For quantities:

> *cinq mètres **de** tissu*, *trois kilos **de** sucre*, *trois décilitres **de** vin*.

The absence of article gives it a formal connotation.

The last sub-case (your question) is the perhaps the most difficult to grasp. Let's say (though it may seem a little idiotic) that these are cases where there is a quantity of something, but that thing is enumerable. How can one have a singular to describe a number of something that should be a plural?

A few examples should clarify this:

> *Des études **de** médecin*
>
> *Une étude **de** notaire*
>
> *Une réponse **de** Normand* (peut-être bien que oui, peut-être bien que non).

In essence, it is the cases where all elements of the **category** have been fused into a singular noun (approximately: "des études du type pour les médecins", "une étude comme celle de tous les notaires", "une réponse typique des Normands").

And finally your answer, as this is a **social category**:

> *Il l'a traitée **de** vieille fille*.

Phew!